# Extract a between a specific pattern

Tags: regex, groovy, extract

I have to extract some substrings, this is like an XML markup in a plain text doc, like

```
lsdkfjsdklfj sdklfsdklfjsd <AAA>myString</AAA>sdfsdfsdfsdf
```

Can i extract this pattern in a single command?

In a case like this, I tried to use a matcher, the group command to extract this single match.

I don't want to do something like

```
String pattern = /<AAA>(.*)<\/AAA>/;

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher("lsdkfjsdklfj sdklfsdklfjsd <AAA>myString</AAA>sdfsdfsdfsdf");
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
}
```

There must be a more elegant way.

Edit : 
Thank you time_yates, i was looking for something like that.

Could you explain a little why you use [0][1] on the result of

```
def extract = (input =~ '<AAA>(.+?)</AAA>')[0][1]
```

Answer by tim_yates :

=~ returns a Matcher, and so [0] gets the first match, which is 2 groups, the first is the String that had the match in it (your whole string) the second [1] is the group you defined in your expression

Thank you so much for your help, and thanks to all the readers.
Power of a community !!!

Comment: Whats the problem with using regex and a matcher?

Comment: how can you use js-like regex in Java?

Comment: i just think it's a little long :)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou you can't. OP's code won't compile like this.

Comment: @julienasefth if you think it's long, create a method which takes two string/regex values and input and returns extracted text as a single string or a list.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
def input = 'lsdkfjsdklfj sdklfsdklfjsd <AAA>myString</AAA>sdfsdfsdfsdf'
def extract = (input =~ '<AAA>(.+?)</AAA>')[0][1]
assert extract == 'myString'
```

Comment: Thank you time_yates, i was looking for something like that.

Could you explain a little why you use [0][1] on the result of

def extract = (input =~ '<AAA>(.+?)</AAA>')[0][1]

Comment: `=~` returns a Matcher, and so `[0]` gets the first match, which is 2 groups, the first is the String that had the match in it (your whole string) the second `[1]` is the group you defined in your expression

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and thanks to all the readers.
Power of a community !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest (not the best) way I can think of without external libs:

```
String str = "lsdkfjsdklfj sdklfsdklfjsd <AAA>myString</AAA>sdfsdfsdfsdf";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf(">") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("<")));
```

Or using [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) (which is million times better than my previous sugestion with substring):

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "<AAA>", "</AAA>");
```

Still I'd go with `matcher()` like you proposed among all these.